# Problem with updating a plugin

Tags: plugins, ftp

I install WordPress locally on Ubuntu. But when I wanted to update plug-in or install a theme a pop-up open and asks to enter hostname. At first I didn't know what to enter. Trying some of options I entered 192.168.1.1 it worked But it shows an error:Username/Password incorrect
I don't remember FTP anywhere. I just entered My SQL pass and wordpress user and pass. None of them worked.

Comment: This is a file permissions/ownership issue - you're most likely running your local web server under a different user to the owner of your WordPress installation, and so WP falls back to it's FTP filesystem. You might find [this quick fix](http://www.barrykooij.com/unable-to-install-plugins-on-localhost/) solves it (if the web server user still has write permissions) - otherwise you will need to chown your install, or set up PHP fast CGI or similar.

Comment: the pop-up won't show but it won't update.

Comment: Changing files+directories owner to `www-data:www-data` worked for me. Then in order to be able to edit the files, your user account (the one you're using to log into ubuntu) must belong to `www-data` group.